# Check if an element is present in another vector and print its value

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to write a simple loop which checks if any element of `a.sub` is present in `a`, then extract that element and print its value

```
a.sub <- c(22,3)
a <- seq(1: 10)

if(a.sub %in% a){

  present <-  a.sub[a.sub %in% a] # this extract the value in `a.sub` which is present in `a` 
  print(present)

} else {

  print("no element is present")
}

"no element is present"
Warning message:
  In if (a.sub %in% a) { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why is the loop not printing `3` since 3 is present in both `a.sub` and `a`?

Comment: For length of vector greater than 1, use `ifelse` i.e. or if it is to find no element, then wrap the call with `any` or `all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use `if/else`, one thing to consider is the length of the output generated by the condition.  The `if/else` expects a logical output of length 1 and is not vectorized.  Here, the issue is to check whether there are `any` elements of one vector in another vector

```
if(any(a.sub %in% a)) print(a.sub[a.sub %in% a]) else print("No element present")
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement will only take the first argument into consideration and throw a warning message. If you want to print the result for all the values in a.sub, use `ifelse` like this:

```
ifelse(a.sub %in% a, a.sub, "Not found")
```